# Finding the position of decimal point in an integer or a string

Tags: r

If i want to determine the position of a decimal point in an integer, for example, in 524.79, the position of the decimal point is 4, and that is what I want as output in R; which function or command should i use? I have tried using gregexpr as well as regexpr but each time the output comes out to be 1.

This is what I did :

```
x <- 524.79

gregexpr(pattern = ".", "x")
```

The output looks like this:

```
[[1]]

[1] 1

attr(,"match.length")

[1] 1

attr(,"useBytes")

[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.` is a metacharacter which means any character.  It either needs to be escaped (`\\.`) or place it inside square brackets `[.]` or use `fixed = TRUE` to get the literal character

```
as.integer(gregexpr(pattern = ".", x, fixed = TRUE))
#[1] 4
```

---

Or a compact option is `str_locate`

```
library(stringr)
unname(str_locate(x, "[.]")[,1])
#[1] 4
```

---

The second issue in the OP's solution is quoting the object `x`.  So, the `gregexpr` locates the `.` as 1 because there is only one character "x" and it is the first position

#### data

```
x <- 524.79
```

Answer (score 3):

We could actually use a regex here:

```
x <- "524.79"
nchar(sub("(?<=\\.)\\d+", "", x, perl=TRUE))

4
```